# Cordova build android failing due to JAVA_HOME error

Tags: cordova

I am on mac and trying to build my cordova project for Android. Whenever I run `cordova build android` I get following error:

```
$ cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/sharmanitin/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
Subproject Path: CordovaLib

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

Result for ECHO $JAVA_HOME:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Both JAVA and JAVAC command work fine in my terminal. Also, not sure if it matters buy I am using [zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) instead of bash on my mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it's not a valid directory.
The error itself says its an incorrect directory.

To set the path correctly :-

Check if /usr/libexec/java_home exists.

If it does then try running

export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`

Comment: Hey Parth, I do NOT have "/usr/libexec/java_home" on my mac. I can see all my java files under /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home Any suggestion how to create  or migrate this? Also if the path is wrong why would java/javac commands work in terminal?

Comment: NVM Got it. I had to create a folder folder java_home under /usr/libexec and  copy past all the contents of /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home and finally change the java_home path by running export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home Thanks for your help

Comment: @nitinsh99 Glad that it helped to some extend :)